# How to make one CheckBox (from hyperref) status dependent on other CheckBoxes'?

Tags: xetex, hyperref, cross-referencing, conditionals, ocgx2

I want to have four CheckBoxes A, B, C and D:

B，C and D change their status on mouse click, in the usual way. And A is checked automatically only when all B, C and D are checked, A doesn't response to mouse click.

[image: Illustration]
The CheckBox status can also be saved.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. You want this done in **Latex**? I had no idea Latex can now do GUI and read mouse clicks also (not been following Tikz development lately). But may be Javascript might be easier for this task than Latex?

Comment: Yes, I want this done in LaTex. Features like `ocmd` from package `ocgx2` can do similar work, but the status cannot be saved. So I wonder if there is a way to do this.

Comment: I see. I did not know about these packages, should look into it.  Thanks.

Comment: you probably will need javascript.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer  Yep, it seems difficult with LaTex. I'll try Javascript. Thanks

Comment: eforms supports RadioButtoms, which includes a group title and \A options for actions (javascript).

Comment: @ John Kormylo Thanks for telling me this!